# Why does the parameterized version of this query run slower than a non-parameterized version?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Sample Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test (@p varchar(10))
AS
DECLARE @param varchar(10)
SET @param = @p + '%'

SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = tr.id
WHERE t2.desc LIKE @param
```

I've a query which is similar to one above and when i use this in stored procedure it runs indefinitely without giving any output. But if i use same query as,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = tr.id
WHERE t2.desc LIKE 'A%'  -- notice no parameter here
```

This executes in less than a second.

My table2 has 140K records and table1 some 250K

Any idea what could be causing like operator to run slow?

Comment: Have you looked at an explain plan for the query?

Comment: Based on your tests, it doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the like key word at all, since even the fast version includes that operator.

Comment: i tried running both and it runs less than a sec when i use parameters directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not know at compile time that `@param` will not have a leading wildcard so when it compiles the batch it gives you a plan with a scan not a seek.

You could maybe try `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION (FORCESEEK)` (SQL Server 2008) to see if it gives you a better plan.

Comment: OPTION(RECOMPILE) worked. Now it runs less than a second. My original query has 4 inner joins and 3 left outer joins.

Comment: @rs - After doing some testing though I'm beginning to doubt my explanation. When I look at the stored procedure plan I see that both end up with an index range seek. The parameterised version has a compute scalar operator that calls `LikeRangeStart` and `LikeRangeEnd`. It actually uses this range seek even when there is a leading wildcard. What do your execution plans look like? Wondering if collation can make a difference (or maybe it is just a question of skewed statistics meaning that it alters the order of the operators)

Comment: I also don't think that is the reason. I'm seeing the same behavior. OPTION (RECOMPILE) does help, but I can't inject that into the EF generated query.